# How to access context object in Step Function Map state?

Tags: aws-step-functions

I want to access State Machine input from context object. The AWS [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-contextobject.html) says I can access the context object from `ItemsPath` and `InputPath`. So I am trying something like this:

```
{
 "StartAt": "Map",
 "States": {
   "Map": {
   "Type": "Map",
   "ItemsPath.$": "$$.Execution.Input",
   "MaxConcurrency": 2,
   "Iterator": {
     ...
   }
 }
}
```

But this is giving me syntax error (ItemsPath.$ is not supported). Has anybody tried to do this? I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `ItemsPath.$`, simply use `ItemsPath`:

```
{
 "StartAt": "Map",
 "States": {
   "Map": {
   "Type": "Map",
   "ItemsPath": "$$.Execution.Input",
   "MaxConcurrency": 2,
   "Iterator": {
     ...
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: Annoyingly, the docs say: "To access the context object, first specify the parameter name by appending .$ to the end, as you do when selecting state input with a path."